# Blueman causes nautilus-sendto to crash!

Tags: bluetooth, context-menu

After installing `blueman`, the "Send to" option in nautilus doesn't work anymore, Nothing happens when you click on it.

#### output of `nautilus-sendto random file` :

```
Init pidgin plugin
Init evolution plugin
Init nautilus burn plugin
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: specified class size for type 'PyGtkGenericCellRenderer' is smaller than the parent type's 'GtkCellRenderer' class size
  from gtk import _gtk
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: g_type_get_qdata: assertion 'node != NULL' failed
  from gtk import _gtk
Segmentation fault
```

Removing `blueman` fixes the problem, but i need `blueman` in order for my bluetooth to work.
It says [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/blueman/+bug/956124) that a fix was released in version 1.23

### but i'am already running 1.23!!

Comment: Your Ubuntu version is?

Comment: This is a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/blueman/+bug/956124

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10 saucy

Comment: I am already running version 1.23 !

Comment: i have edited my question

Comment: Try to remove all files from `/usr/lib/nautilus-sendto`, but not `plugins` directory. `plugins` directory should contain only these files: libnstbluetooth.so  libnstevolution.so  libnstremovable_devices.so
libnstburn.so       libnstgajim.so      libnstupnp.so
libnstempathy.so    libnstpidgin.so

Comment: You should still report a bug.

Comment: I will, @Braiam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to fix `nautilus-sendto`
I removed `libnstblueman.a` & `libnstblueman.so` from the folder `/usr/lib/nautilus-sendto/plugins`

> sudo rm /usr/lib/nautilus-sendto/plugins/libnstblueman.a
>   sudo rm /usr/lib/nautilus-sendto/plugins/libnstblueman.so

This isn't really a fix cause it will remove blueman from "send to" destinations, but that doesn't bug me because i only need `blueman` so i can use `bluez` (it somehow fixes the `GDbus erro...` error when transferring files).

Thanks for "Radu Rădeanu" for pointing me to this.